# YII 2.0 GridView update

Tags: gridview, yii2

I've got problem with updating yiigridview via javascript.
I'm trying to use it yii 1.1 way:

```
jQuery.fn.yiigridview.update('grid-id');
```

but this gets me the error: `'undefined is not a function'`
How to update the whole GridView widget (or only one row) in Yii framework 2.0 using javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found solution here http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/655/how-to-use-gridview-with-ajax/
Using pjax:

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#idofyourpjaxwidget'});
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also use Yii2 callback:

```
$("#your-grid-id").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
```